# Send myself an email using php when a user reports someone in my parse database app

Tags: php, email, parsing, back4app

I have a mobile app, and the database is hosted on back4app (parse database). I have a class called `ChatRooms` and the object is `isReported`. I would like to send  myself an email when `isReported = True`.

I would like to use php to do this if all possible. I'm really not sure how to setup the phpSDK for parse.

Comment: There is a mail function in PHP use that? Not sure about this back4App thing. Tried there community support?
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/back4app

Comment: In wich programming language you can write code for parse DB???

Comment: I want to write the code in php

Comment: Once I can use php to connect to the parse database, then I can use the mail function @RichardHousham

Comment: But my point is just write a trigger method in your programming language, I mean the programming language which you can easily access and check DB parameter (isReported). In that method call a remote PHP file or URL (Like RESTful API) to send email. and to send email just use simple PHP function mail() using your SMTP.

Comment: why you want PHP, just to send email??? If yes then write email logic using php (accessible via URL) and check DB value using your programming language and call REST API (URL/PHP hosted location) to send .

Comment: It is far away easier you do it using Back4app cloud code (http://docs.back4app.com/docs/integrations/) instead of running a PHP only for this. Create a afterSave trigger to the ChatRooms class (http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#aftersave-triggers), check the value of isReported and use for example SendGrid to send the e-mail (http://docs.back4app.com/docs/integrations/using-sendgrid-to-send-email/).